# Access springbeans in JerseyTest with Jersey2.0

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jersey-2.0, jersey-test-framework

I have jersey project with spring. Now My test is deriverd from JerseyTest. When I try to do

```
@AutoWired 
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

It looks like spring is not working in jersey test. I did some research and found some links like
[spring_jersey](http://geek.riffpie.com/unit-testing-restful-jersey-services-glued-together-with-spring/)
but it did not work ,since I am using jersey2.0.

My code looks like

```
 //AbstractTest 
    package com.test;


            import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
            import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

        import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
        import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
        import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
        import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
        import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
        import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
        import org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.ValidationFeature;

        public abstract class AbstractTest extends JerseyTest
        {
            protected WebTarget getRootTarget(final String rootResource)
            {
                return client().target(getBaseUri()).path(rootResource);
            }

            @Override
            protected final Application configure()
            {
                final ResourceConfig application = configureApplication();

                // needed for json serialization
                application.register(JacksonFeature.class);

                // bean validation
                application.register(ValidationFeature.class);

                // configure spring context
                application.property("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:/META-INF/applicationContext.xml");

                // disable bean validation for tests
                application.property(ServerProperties.BV_FEATURE_DISABLE, "true");

                return application;
            }

            protected abstract ResourceConfig configureApplication();

            @Override
            protected void configureClient(final ClientConfig config)
            {
                // needed for json serialization
                config.register(JacksonFeature.class);

                config.register(new LoggingFilter(java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AbstractResourceTest.class.getName()), false));

                super.configureClient(config);
            }
        }



    package com.test;

    import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.content;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.method;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.client.response.MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess;

    //MyTest
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.FileReader;
        import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;
    import org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

    import junit.framework.Assert;

    public final class MyTest extends AbstractTest
        {

        private static final String ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH = "/testUrl";

        @AutoWired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
        private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;


        @Before
        public void setup(){
            this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            this.mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
        }

        @Test
        public void testPostWithString() {

            WebTarget target = getRootTarget(ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH).path("");
            String entityBody = new String();
            entityBody = " My test data";


            final javax.ws.rs.client.Entity<String> entity = javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(entityBody, "text/plain");


            mockServer.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH)).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST)).andExpect(content().string(entityBody))
                    .andRespond(withSuccess("resultSuccess", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));


            final Response response = target.request().post(entity);
            Assert.assertNotNull("Response must not be null", response.getEntity());
            Assert.assertEquals("Response does not have expected response code", 200, response.getStatus());

            System.out.println("Response = " + response.getEntity());

            String data = response.readEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println("Response = " + data);
            if(response.ok() != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Ok");
            }
        }
    }
```

Update:

```
public class SimpleJerseyTest extends ApplicationContextAwareJerseyTest {
    private static final String ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH = "/test";

    @Override
    public void configureApplication(ResourceConfig config) {
        config.register(MyApp.class);
        config.register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        try{
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)this.applicationContext).refresh();
            super.setUp();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    this.mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Test
    public void doitOnce() {
        WebTarget target = target(ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH);

        String entityBody = new String();

        final javax.ws.rs.client.Entity<String> entity = javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(entityBody, "text/plain");


        mockServer.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH)).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST)).andExpect(content().string(entityBody))
                .andRespond(withSuccess("resultSuccess", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));


        final Response response = target.request().post(entity);


        System.out.println("Response = " + response.getEntity());

        String data = response.readEntity(String.class);

        System.out.println("Response = " + data);
        if(response.ok() != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

I have added bean in

> src/test/resources/META-INF/applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- Our REST Web Service client -->
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"/>
```

Same bean I have added in

> src/main/resources/META-INF/applicationContext.xml

```
!-- Our REST Web Service client -->
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of configuring Spring like this

```
application.property("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:/META-INF/applicationContext.xml");
```

You can instead use

```
application.property("contextConfig", <ApplicationContext>);
```

This way you can have an instance of the `ApplicationContext`, where you can get the [`AutowireCapableBeanFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html). With this, you can just call `acbf.autowireBean(this)` to inject the test class.

Here's what I mean. I tested it, and it works find for simple cases. Won't work well though if the beans you are trying to inject *aren't* singletons, as new one will be create for the test and where ever else you try to inject to in your application code

```
public abstract class ApplicationContextAwareJerseyTest extends JerseyTest {

    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    protected final ResourceConfig configure() {
        final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        configureApplication(config);

        this.applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        config.property("contextConfig", this.applicationContext);
        final AutowireCapableBeanFactory bf = this.applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        bf.autowireBean(this);
        return config;
    }

    public final ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return this.applicationContext;
    }

    protected void configureApplication(ResourceConfig resourceConfig) {};
}
```

One thing I am not sure about though is how the resetting would work. I tried to add

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)this.applicationContext).refresh();
    super.setUp();
}
```

into the abstract class, but that doesn't seem to work as expected. The test I used is as follows

```
public class SimpleJerseyTest extends ApplicationContextAwareJerseyTest {


    @Path("test")
    public static class SimpleResource {
        @Autowired
        private MessageService service;

        @GET
        public String getMessage() {
            return this.service.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configureApplication(ResourceConfig config) {
        config.register(SimpleResource.class);
        config.register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        assertEquals("Hello World", messageService.getMessage());
    }

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    @Test
    public void doitOnce() {
        messageService.setMessage("BOOYAH");
        final Response response = target("test").request().get();
        assertEquals("BOOYAH", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void doitTwice() {
        messageService.setMessage("BOOYAH");
        final Response response = target("test").request().get();
        assertEquals("BOOYAH", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

The result I would get for the second test is that the value of the service message was the default message `"Hello World"`, even though I set the message to `"BOOYAH"`. This tells me that there is a stale service in the application, which is not the same one being injected into the test. The first test works fine though. Without resetting, the second test would work fine also, but you are left with modified services in each test, which makes the test not self-contained.

Comment: Thanks,but I am still facing issue. I have create RestTemplate bean in main application,In test class I am also using Restemplate.Now when I execute test resttemplate in main application is coming as null and not able to proccesd with test.

Comment: Did you use `META-INF/applicationContext.xml` instead of the `applicationContext.xml` I used. I had the file at the root of the classpath when testing, not in the `META-INF` like you have it

Comment: GIve me a few minutes. I will post the complete repo to github.

Comment: My application is a rest client which makes call to rest end point. I am testing it, so can we mock resttemplate in main app using MockRestServiceServer

Comment: I don't think I completely understand what the MockRestServiceService is used for, but [here is what I used to test](https://github.com/psamsotha/jerseytest-with-spring-inject).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130657/discussion-between-alien01-and-peeskillet).